# How to enable service logon on Windows 10 Home?

Tags: windows-10

I am currently trying to install Jenkins CI, in which I need to enable the service logon on an account present on my machine. However, the "tutorials" I followed ask for Windows software called "Local Group Policy Editor", the problem is, I don't have this software on my machine (apparently it was removed). Is there another way for me to enable Service Logon?

Comment: Windows Home Edition is very definitely reduced in capability from Pro. You should probably upgrade to Pro.

Comment: Only Pro and Enterprise editions have support for `gpedit.msc` [Group Policy Editor]

Comment: Is `services.msc` present on Home? When you use an account for a service there, it is automatically granted the “Log on as a service” privilege.

Comment: @DanielB - All editions allow you to mange the services running on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Power Shell script for installing Group Policy Editor on Windows Home.  Please review this article below:

- [Adding GP Editor to Windows Home](https://www.itechtics.com/enable-gpedit-windows-10-home/#Download_and_Install_GPEditmsc_in_Windows_10_Home_using_PowerShell_script)
- [GPEdit Enabler script](https://GPEdit%20Enabler%20for%20Windows%2010%20Home%20Edition)

  > ```powershell
  > @echo off  pushd "%~dp0"
  >
  > dir /b
  > %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientExtensions-Package~3*.mum >List.txt
  > dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientTools-Package~3*.mum >>List.txt
  >
  > for /f %%i in ('findstr /i . List.txt 2^>nul') do dism /online /norestart /add-package:"%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\%%i"
  > pause
  > ```

  This is a simple PowerShell script that will install the disabled Group Policy feature in the Windows 10 Home edition:

  - Right-click the downloaded `gpedit-enabler.bat`, selecting Run as Administrator to start the installation process. It may take some time depending upon your system performance and once the process is complete, press any key to close the command prompt window.

**A much better approach:**  Upgrade to Windows 10 Pro (easy and simple) as you will then have all the Windows 10 Pro tools.

Comment: I didn't realize it when I edited, but the _GPEdit Enabler Script_ link is lacking the web address _(I also forgot to move `pushd "%~dp0"` to its own line and combine the second command onto one line - e.g. `dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientExtensions-Package~3*.mum >List.txt`)_

Comment: [Policy Plus](https://github.com/Fleex255/PolicyPlus) is an alternative to using a the method described.  There are still policies that will only be respected on Windows 10 Professional. The policy editor will not make you aware of those restrictions since it normally does not exist on Windows 10 Home.  Since Windows 10 Home cannot connect to a AD domain there is little reason to mention it.  In this case the policy responsible likely isn't restricted to a particular edition and can be accomplished with a simple registry key.